# How to remove from a list the strings that have less than N tokens?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list of strings, say:

```
a = ['hey','hey how are you','good how are you','I am', 'I am fine 8998','9809 908']
```

How can I remove the strings that have less than three tokens?:

```
a = ['hey how are you','good how are you', 'I am fine 8998']
```

I tried to:

```
' '.join(a.split(' ')[3:])
```

However, its not working. Any idea of how to remove all the strings that have less than three tokens

Comment: `[_a for _a in a if len(_a.split()) >= 3]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i in a if len(i.split())>=3]
['hey how are you', 'good how are you', 'I am fine 8998']
```

Comment: @slider but OP said `less than` no?

Answer (score 6):

This is another way of doing the same using `filter` and `lambda`:

```
a = ['hey','hey how are you','good how are you','I am', 'I am fine 8998','9809 908']

res = list(filter(lambda x: x.count(' ') >= 2, a))
# ['hey how are you', 'good how are you', 'I am fine 8998']
```

Or:

```
res = list(filter(lambda x: len(x.split()) >= 3, a))
```

Comment: Counting spaces... 2 should be enough, no? :-)